# MySQL: The query is much slower first time but faster after that even if new data is inserted

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table named `data_table`.

This table already has about 10 million records. Previously I used to check if combination of `itemID`, `FromDate` and `ToDate` exists before inserting data. To make things easier I created `unique` index with fields `itemID+FromDate+ToDate`.

This table has now all together three indexes, `ID` (Pk), `itemID` and `UniqueIndex`

**Problem**

1. The first time if I try to generate report for say `itemID=2630`, and for date range `2018-01-01` to `2021-01-01`. It takes around 60 seconds.
2. Second time for same parameters, it takes around 1 second.
3. I then deleted all data for this item (2630) , and reinserted many random data for this itemID between selected date range.
4. Now if I run the report third time, it still takes around 1 second.

I thought first time, the query results was cached so second time it was very fast.
In third step I removed all data and re inserted different records and then generated the report, but it was as fast as second time. For particular item, why first time the report generation process is very slow? Can anybody help me how to overcome this issue?

The table engine I use is `innodb` and my mysql version is 5.7.33

**Update**
This is my query

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  DataTable AS D 
WHERE ItemID = :ItemID 
  AND IsJoined = '0' 
  AND (
    (
      :paramFromDate < ToDate 
      AND ToDate < :paramToDate
    ) 
    OR (
      :paramFromDate < FromDate 
      AND FromDate < :paramToDate
    ) 
    OR (
      FromDate < :paramFromDate 
      AND :paramToDate < FromDate
    )
  ) 
ORDER BY FromDate DESC
```

**UPDATE**
Restarting mysql, causes the query slow again. And subsequent queries are fast until I restart mysql again.

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you've solved the problem. For help with query optimisation , we'd generally need to see some stuff, none of which is here.

Comment: @Strawberry I have added my query, I forgot to add that one sorry

Answer (score 2):

**Caching**

The main cache for InnoDB is the "buffer_pool".  It caches blocks (16KB each) each of which contains several consecutive rows of data or rows of an index.  All operations (read or write) of rows work with those blocks.

After starting or restarting MySQL, the cache is empty.  Hence, everything needs to be fetched from disk, hence 'slow'.

After reading the data once (and getting the relevant blocks pulled into cache, a second query will find them cached and be 'fast'.

Inserted rows require the relevant block(s) to be in the cache.  So, for some time after doing an an `INSERT` a `SELECT` of those rows will be 'fast'.

**Better INDEX**

As for optimizing *that* query, have

```
INDEX(ItemID, IsJoined, FromDate)   -- (in this order)
```

The first two columns help with part of the `WHERE`.

The `OR` in the rest of the `WHERE` prevents any useful optimization involving the two date columns.

However, the Optimizer *may* be able to avoid a sort (for the `ORDER BY`) if it chooses to use the `FromDate` that I added to the index.

If you are checking for overlapping date ranges, see if this meets your needs:

```
AND  fromDate <= :toParam
AND  :fromParam <= toDate
```

If that works for you, then another part of the `WHERE` is handled by my index.  (But it will not be possible to also have the other part handled.)  (Also, I don't know whether you need `<` or `<=`.)

Comment: But combination of `ItemID`, `FromDate` and `ToDate` must be unique, so I created unique index. Shall i keep it as it is or drop it? If i drop, won't there be chance of duplicates?

Comment: @WatsMyName - Keep the `UNIQUE` index you have; add my recommendation.

Comment: ok thanks, I have one more question, there is another condition in `where` clause that may or may not come depending upon user's selection. The condition is `AND DutyFree='1'`. Shall I put this column `DutyFree` in the index you recommended? If yes what is the better order?